# How to set a Background image in UNO UWP?

Tags: xaml, uno-platform

I am trying to put a background image, so far I have this code:

```
<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Windows-10-Hero-Ninja-Cat-1024x576-03a71eed2a427425.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

Which appears this way on UWP on Windows 10:

[image: UWP on Windows 10]

But when I Build the WASM or Android, the Background image does not appear.

[image: Edge]

[image]

The file property is set Build action: Content, Copy to output directory: Do not copy.

[image]

Comment: This should work now in more recent versions of Uno.

Answer (score 6):

Uno's WASM target is still experimental and some features are not available yet. The only yet implemented *background brush* is `SolidColorBrush`.

It's implemented for iOS ([source code here](https://github.com/nventive/Uno/blob/master/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/Media/ImageBrush.iOS.cs)), but not Android.

Since you're already in a `<Grid>`, you can simply put your image as first element:

```
  <Grid>
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Windows-10-Hero-Ninja-Cat-1024x576-03a71eed2a427425.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    [... put your other controls here]
  </Grid>
```

Comment: I bet you can help me out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919882/how-to-use-mediaelement-to-play-sound-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to use different background approaches for each platform use xaml conditional prefixes.

https://platform.uno/docs/articles/platform-specific-xaml.html#xaml-conditional-prefixes

You can use  <wasm:Image ... />

At the end of the day you can have the same result with flexible markup.