# How to use `MediaElement` to play sound in Android?

Tags: android, uwp, uwp-xaml, uno-platform

I'm using `MediaElement` to play sound in an Uno-Platform project.

It plays well in the UWP project but doesn't work in the Android project.

The audio file is located in the shared project as *Exclude from project*, and is linked in the UWP project as `Content` and in the Droid project as `AndroidAsset`.

XAML:

```
<MediaElement Source="/Assets/MySound.wav"/>
```

I've also tried accessing it programmatically set the `Source` to `ms-appx:///Assets/MySound.wav` with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaPlayerElement` is now available in Uno (See [MediaPlayerElement](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/controls/MediaPlayerElement.html) documentation)

Answer (score 3):

As of today, local resources are not supported for iOS in the the `Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer` class, but adding support for it should be relatively easy.

On Android, it should work, but there's probably another issue, related to the name of the asset, such as casing (android is lower case) or hyphens (transformed to '_' by android).